# Create Windows Installer Package for Windows Application (Infragistics + MS Office Automation)

Tags: .net, clickonce, office-interop, infragistics, setup-deployment

I need to create a windows installer for a windows application that uses Infragistics control library and Office automation. So far had no luck with Visual Studio ClickOnce installation.

So I created a setup deployment project and it works fine. But I need to add an update feature to the installer.

Are there any open source installers which support my requirements? Or how can I get ClickOnce working?

### ClickOnce error

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO     Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)  Common
>   Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.239     System.Deployment.dll       :
>   4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)  clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>     dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)
>
> SOURCES   Deployment url          : http:///jcms.application
>                         Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>                         X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET   Deployment Provider url     : http:///jcms.application    Application url         :
>   http:///Application%20Files/jcms_1_0_0_13/jcms.exe.manifest
>                         Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>                         X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
>
> IDENTITIES    Deployment Identity     : jcms.application, Version=1.0.0.13,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e3b9e83a371fb3,
>   processorArchitecture=msil    Application Identity        : jcms.exe,
>   Version=1.0.0.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e3b9e83a371fb3,
>   processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY   * Installable application.
>
> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of
>   http:///jcms.application resulted in exception. Following
>   failure messages were detected:       + Value does not fall within the
>   expected range.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS     * [1/26/2012 6:09:13 PM] : Activation of
>   http:///jcms.application has started.   * [1/26/2012 6:09:18 PM]
>   : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.   *
>   [1/26/2012 6:09:18 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
>     * [1/26/2012 6:09:18 PM] : Processing of application manifest has
>   successfully completed.   * [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Found compatible
>   runtime version 2.0.50727.    * [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting
>   dependent assembly Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>   processorArchitecture=msil using Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>   processorArchitecture=msil.   * [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting
>   dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,
>   processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,
>   processorArchitecture=msil.   * [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting
>   dependent assembly WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil using
>   WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil.  *
>   [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly
>   Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C, processorArchitecture=msil using
>   Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=msil.  *
>   [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Ink,
>   Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35,
>   processorArchitecture=x86 using Microsoft.Ink, Version=6.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=x86.    * [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting
>   dependent assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C,
>   processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c,
>   processorArchitecture=msil.   * [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting
>   dependent assembly System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using
>   System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.  *
>   [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly
>   System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using
>   System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.  *
>   [1/26/2012 6:09:20 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is
>   complete.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [1/26/2012 6:09:21 PM] System.ArgumentException
>         - Value does not fall within the expected range.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32
>   Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId
>   definitionAppId)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId
>   definitionAppId)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState
>   subState)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>   subState)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState
>   subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest
>   appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>   TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
>   available.

Comment: I apologize but I'm not sure I understand what the specific problem is with your application when you attempt to launch the program.  I think this might be an issue with signing your Infragistics libraries.  I have a ClickOnce application that uses Infragistics, however, I deploy my Infragistics components through a separate, MSI installer that is bundled as a prerequisite to my application. It installs the Infragistics components in the Windows GAC.  This helped fix the licensing issue and it has also kept the size of subsequent application updates much smaller.

Comment: There shouldn't be any licensing issue with including the Infragistics assemblies that can be redistributed in the click once deployment.  If you do have issues, you may want to reach out to Infragistics: http://www.infragistics.com/support/get-help.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread about updating an application: [What is the best way to auto update a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395609/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-update-a-windows-application/7396926#7396926)

Basically, good updaters aren't free, so an open-source solution may not work the way you want it. You can either try to work around the ClickOnce error, or try to implement an updater mechanism yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting with you click once deployment may that the path isn't valid, for example it will fail if you have an ampersand in the path:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/725977/394855

Another possibility is that if the path is already used:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/49197a65-92c4-4529-b118-8f20c8c0fbfc/