# ClickOnce: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: clickonce

I have a distributed application via ClickOnce. I updated several times and there has never been a problem.
Since the last update (which was minor: a label), when I run my application from a post, click once start and prompt me an error:
    Application Cannot Be started

When I look at the logs I get the following message:

```
OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [04/10/2012 13:24:33] : Activation of C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx.appref-ms| has started.
* [04/10/2012 13:24:33] : Performing necessary update check as specified by the deployment.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [04/10/2012 13:24:33] System.ArgumentException
- Value does not fall within the expected range.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType,     String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[]     manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION         processInformation)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId             appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId         appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId     appId,     AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean         useActivationParameter)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String      shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

I have traveled the length and breadth of net, but I have not found a solution to my problem.

I do not even understand what is this problem.

I tried this solution without success:
[ClickOnce error: Value does not fall within the expected range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166233/clickonce-error-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range)

And this one too without success: ["Value Does not fall in the expected range" ClickOnce Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704532/value-does-not-fall-in-the-expected-range-clickonce-deployment)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to run the clickonce on a UNC share, it may not work.
I was getting the same result as yours above, but I just tried deploying to C:\ instead of our share, and it runs just fine.  Also, check to make sure you don't have any & ampersands in your deploy path as this seems to muck it up.

Also check out the list of things to check for on this post.
["Value Does not fall in the expected range" ClickOnce Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704532/value-does-not-fall-in-the-expected-range-clickonce-deployment)

Comment: Different stack trace so entirely different problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit delayed, but I found the only solution to solve my problem was this one:

> 99.9% of the time, "value does not fall within expected range" means you have circular references, or references to two different versions of the same assembly.

From here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e6c0a0ca-fbf0-47e2-8681-bc03471d09f6/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range?forum=winformssetup