# ClickOnce setup.exe not working. new problem besides known issue reinstalling?

Tags: c#, windows-10, visual-studio-2022, clickonce, windows-10-iot-enterprise

I am on KB5028849 as latest update and before that a security update KB5028166 was installed.

Are there any other known issue's besides what is currently known about clickonce app need to be reinstalled because of a windows update? because I have something else, my setup.exe isn't working. I just made a new build of my app. and the build works fine but when I want to deploy it with clickonce setup.exe it says "can't start application, contact your software supplier" (roughly translate dutch to English).
I have made multiple builds in the past of my app with the clickonce option without any problems.

I know its working fine because the .exe file of the app itself in the folder "Application Files" >> then folder of latest build launches the "MyApp.exe" just fine (made a build without .DEPLOY extension).

when launching the setup.exe it says something like the value is not within expected reach. (error report translated some because was in dutch)

ERROR SUMMARY Below you'll find an overview of the errors. Further details about these errors can be found later in the log.

Activation of C:xxx\xxx\AppProject\bin\publish\xxx.application resulted in an exception. The following messages for failed actions have been encountered:
The value does not fall within the expected range.

ERROR DETAILS The following errors were encountered during this operation.

[30-8-2023 22:53:46] System.ArgumentException
The value does not fall within the expected range.
Source: System.Deployment
Stack trace: at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation) at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri) at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl) at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

tried older versions of app but same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727771/clickonce-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it and report back if it solves the issues.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. It was just a case of clearing the Apps 2.0 folder and the issue was resolved! for some users i just needed to clear the folders/files concerning my app and for others the entire 2.0 folder needed to be cleared. uninstalling the app trough control panel was sometimes not enough apperantly.

BE AWARE!!
Clearing the entire folder can lead to complication with other clickonce application installed on the users computer. So do not bring a truck to squash a fly. i was lucky it was an inhouse application just a few people use. I could manualy check their computers.