# "Value does not fall within the expected range." from System.Deployment when installing C#.net app

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I am using the Publish function within Visual Studio 2013 to deploy an application to a server.

When I run the setup.exe it generates, I get a "Cannot Start Application" error.  I have tried a number of things to resolve the issue, including:

- restarting the machine
- changing the file and assembly versions under Project Settings/Application/Assembly Info... and disabling automatic revision incrementing per ["Value Does not fall in the expected range" ClickOnce Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704532/value-does-not-fall-in-the-expected-range-clickonce-deployment)
- changed the target CPU to x86 per ["Value Does not fall in the expected range" ClickOnce Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704532/value-does-not-fall-in-the-expected-range-clickonce-deployment)

Any ideas?

Below is the complete paste from the "Details..." file:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17929
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)
```

```
SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/bgapp/xmltest.application
    Application url         : file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/bgapp/Application%20Files/xmltest_1_0_1_0/xmltest.exe.manifest
```

```
IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : xmltest.application, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7d533deea4ca951b, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : xmltest.exe, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7d533deea4ca951b, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32
```

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY

Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.

```
* Activation of C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bgapp\xmltest.application resulted in exception.  Following failure messages were detected:
    + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [3/31/2014 7:32:14 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bgapp\xmltest.application has started.
    * [3/31/2014 7:32:15 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [3/31/2014 7:32:15 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [3/31/2014 7:32:15 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [3/31/2014 7:32:16 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [3/31/2014 7:32:16 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [3/31/2014 7:32:16 PM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

```
COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Does this server have the same version of .NET installed that you developed this application with?

Comment: The development machine has the following "Microsoft .NET Framework" versions installed (under Control Panel - Programs and Features): 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack; 4.5 SDK; 4.5.1; 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack; 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU); 4.5.1 SDK.  The server machine had these versions installed: 4 Multi-Targeting Pack; 4.5.  I ran Windows Update on the server and installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1.  So now the 2 versions on the server are: 4 Multi-Targeting Pack and 4.5.  Under Project/Settings/Application, Target Framework is 4.5. Even after installing 4.5.1, it's still not working.

Comment: VS2013 builds to .NET 4.5.1 by default, which your server may not have. Try going back to your application and changing the version of .NET you are compiling for.

Comment: Currently the app is set to target .NET Framework 4.5.  Now that I have 4.5.1 installed on the server, should I change to target .NET Framework 4.5.1? If I select that, I get a warning that "Changing Target Framework may require manual modification of project files in order to build."

Comment: I changed the target to .NET 4.5.1, and still getting the same issue.