# Installing Github on Windows- "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: windows, github

I'm trying to install Github on my Windows 7 laptop, and I get an error every time I run the GitHubSetup.exe, saying "Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.". When I hit details, this is the text that shows:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18444
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
                    Server      : AmazonS3

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=2.4.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.
* Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [10/17/2014 5:20:08 PM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
* [10/17/2014 5:20:09 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [10/17/2014 5:20:09 PM] System.ArgumentException
    - Value does not fall within the expected range.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
* Transaction at [10/17/2014 5:20:09 PM]
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
        - Status: Set
        - HRESULT: 0x0
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
        - HRESULT: 0x0
```

I'm pretty confused, and new to all this, so I'd appreciate any help to figure out installing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try some of the solutions of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1166233/6309):

- make sure the app is not installed or uninstall it (Control Panel)
- run "`rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache`"
- if this isn't enough, try again after a reboot
- removing any references to in the registry (but that was not enough) and then clearing `%user%\AppData\Local\Apps`
- try again as a different user account

The OP [vmazur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4155518/vmazur) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435261/installing-github-on-windows-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range/26436406#comment41632809_26436406):

> My problem was solved by going to `%LocalAppData%\Apps` and **deleting a folder called "`2.0`"** there.

[bkribbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4450618/bkribbs) cautions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435261/installing-github-on-windows-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range/26436406#comment50076916_26436406):

> **That `2.0` folder contains the data from multiple applications**, I assume all the clickonce ones.
>   It would be worth going into that folder, expanding the names, and only deleting the ones with the app name in the folder name. **Otherwise you risk losing other applications as well**.

Comment: My problem was solved by going to %LocalAppData%\Apps and deleting a folder called "2.0" there, but thank you :)

Comment: @vmazur Great. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: That 2.0 folder contains the data from multiple applications, I assume all the clickonce ones. It would be worth going into that folder, expanding the names, and only deleting the ones with the app name in the folder name. Otherwise you risk losing other applications as well.

Comment: @bkribbs good point. I have included your caveat in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and fixed it by restoring the application to previous state.

- Open Control panel
- Open programs and features
- Find GitHub and double click it.
- Select restore application to previous state

Open github

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the issue and here is how I fixed it.

Error logged showed that there were some dependency for different dlls.

- Completely uninstall the application and if possible check for any folder under AppData/2.0 - If there is, delete it after making sure that you are only deleting your application folders only [ as mentioned in the accepted answer].
- Go to project properties -> Publish ->Application Files.

[image]

- Reset All

[image]

Republished the application and installed again and it worked.