# VB.net Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider Error On client PC

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm Using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and .net framwork 4.5.1
when i Publish my solution and install on client PC its showing me Error for Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider missing... I also Included the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider in Published Files.
And if i'm installing in my own pc its Showing me error "Application cannot be Started. Contact the Application Vendor" Here is the Details of the Error.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///D:/Publish/test/Inventory.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Inventory.application, Version=0.9.0.88, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=953af74a0fd8ab19, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of D:\Publish\test\Inventory.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [13-03-17 1:01:10 PM] : Activation of D:\Publish\test\Inventory.application has started.
    * [13-03-17 1:01:11 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [13-03-17 1:01:11 PM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    * Transaction at [13-03-17 1:01:11 PM]
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
            - HRESULT: 0x0
```

And Sorry For My English

Comment: The solutions here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435261/installing-github-on-windows-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range

Comment: Dear Pang Thank you for your Suggestion.... but still no Luck...