# App is not publishing : Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, publish

I have a c# app that is not publishing this time , I published it before without problem.
here is the errors:

```
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2014-01-29 09:57:28] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

since last time I did small change :

```
var existingFCD = fcs.SingleOrDefault(fcd => fcd.FC != null && SWComparer.AreEqual(cea2pFC, fcd.FC));
```

changed to :

```
var existingFCD = fcs.SingleOrDefault(fcd => fcd.FC != null && SWComparer.AreEqual(cea2pFC, fcd.FC) && rat.Name == cea2pFC.Name);
```

can anybody help ?

Comment: What have you changed since last time you published? Do you have a code repository that can show you what has changed?

Comment: I added my changes in the question

Comment: The errors seems to be within Clickonce. If the change is indeed the only change, it should not be the cause.
Maybe restart your pc and Visual studio...check if some addon causes the problem by starting safe mode.

Comment: Maybe you have an ampersand in the path?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699173/clickonce-deployment-errors?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I removed the app from control panel and returned to my previous version finally I was able to manage to fix the problem!