# deployment error Value does not fall within the expected range windows forms application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, deployment, directx

I created a Windows Forms application (based on a few libraries) that is intended to capture sound from a computer and then broadcast it to an online radio service.

The problem that I can't seem to get my head around is deployment. The application works perfectly fine when run from VS debugger, but when I publish the application using OneClick it shows me this error:

> Activation of C:..\RJsimpson.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>           + Value does not fall within the expected range.

The stack trace is :

```
System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

The source code is [here](https://github.com/nader2560/RJsimpson-project). Feel free to download it and try to create an install file.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699173/clickonce-deployment-errors?rq=1)

Comment: Yes I did and the answer says that I should creat a new project and copy past every thing I don't think that is the best solution out there thanks though